# How to make a function that can be called on an object the same way as the member functions for that class?

Tags: c++, function

For example, if you have an object of the std::string class, you can call the `compare(string str)` function as follows:

```
myString.compare(myOtherString);
```

How can I make my own function that I can call on a string in the same way? Example:

```
myString.contains(char[] chars);
```

Comment: @PiotrS.:  I get the sense that that's the question OP is trying to ask.

Comment: You can switch to C# :D

Comment: If you're asking if you can *add* to an existing, closed, class definition, no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add member functions to existing classes in C++. Instead, write a non-member function

```
bool contains(std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2);
```

and call it as

```
contains(myString, myOtherString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this in C++, and you shouldn't try.  Sure, you could inherit from std::string and implement your methods, but then your methods will be unusable from regular strings.  In C++ we do not try too hard to make everything a class method--free functions are functions too!

Comment: You could try, and end up with something like http://www.slideshare.net/phil_nash/c-extension-methods-18678294. But don't do this at home.